# Put external URL into my page

Tags: php, jquery, html, external, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting the content of an element from an external page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336129/extracting-the-content-of-an-element-from-an-external-page)

Is there any way to put external page into my page but not with iframe. Currently I using:

```
<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
echo $homepage;

?>
```

but this is not really elegant solution. Is there some elegant solution for this? maybe with jquery, java script, php ... or some other ... ??? What I need is to show external page but to can see the source code od that external page...

**UPDATE: some browser in browser solution or something similar???**

Comment: You want to _display_ the source code for an external page, or the page itself? In the latter case, use an `<iframe>` and in the former, just print it out in a container or `<pre>` tags.

Comment: I hope you're considering copyright laws in this too... but how is that not an "elegant solution"? It's straight-forward and simple.

Comment: Yes, i if the possible can show the iframe but how to get the source code of external page that showing on my page becouse i'm must have access to source code beouse i needs elements (div,span,p,a,li)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the source code of an external page on your page:

```
<?php

  $url = 'http://www.google.com/';

?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HTML source of <?php echo $url; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($url)); ?>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It,s OK but I'm need to show this code like html like in browser, the source code is behind... i need something that will work like browser!